# Deploying Ruby application on Elastic Beanstalk taking too long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently facing an issue with deploying my Ruby application on Elastic Beanstalk. I'm using the platform "Puma with Ruby 2.3 running on 64-bit Amazon Linux/2.3.3."

The deployment has been ongoing for about 6 hours, and in previous weeks, I never experienced any delays—it was always a smooth process. However, this week, it's taking much longer, and I'm struggling to figure out what might be going wrong. I'm worried about the unusually extended duration of the deployment.

[image]

log of `eb-activity.log`

```
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.185Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.186Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.186Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.rb] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.755Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.rb] : Completed activity.
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.755Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:41.119Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir
  + EB_SUPPORT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/export_envvars
[2023-11-29T04:54:41.119Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Starting activity...
[ec2-user@ip-172-16-0-62 ondeck]$ tail -f /var/log/eb-activity.log 
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.185Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Completed activity.
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.186Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.186Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.rb] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.755Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/01_unzip.rb] : Completed activity.
[2023-11-29T04:54:40.755Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Starting activity...
[2023-11-29T04:54:41.119Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02_setup_envvars.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir
  + EB_SUPPORT_DIR=/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support
  + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/export_envvars
[2023-11-29T04:54:41.119Z] INFO  [2951]  - [Application deployment v.2.0.106-307@606/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/10_bundle_install.sh] : Starting activity...
```

Why would it take this long for deployment? It was so smooth last weeks. Any insights, suggestions, or guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you run database migration on deploy?

Comment: @spickermann No I haven't done database migration on deploy